# how do I loop through an array assign a variable to each item in Objective C

Tags: arrays, objective-c, loops, variables

I have an array that contains 16 items

```
NSArray *centreFreqValues = @[@250, @750, @1250, @1750, @2250, @2750, @3250, @3750, @4250, @5250, @5750, @6250, @6750, @7250, @7750];
```

I have a loop that performs various tasks:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
//do some other stuff
int centreFreq = centreFreqValues[i];
NSLog(@" here is each integer %d", centreFreq);

}
```

but I'm getting the error message:

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an
>   expression of type 'id'

Comment: These are `NSNumber` instances, not `int`. So you can either use `%@` instead of `%d`. Or you can get the `intValue` as Sandy described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either You need to declare an array of integers or while assigning typecast to int.

`[centreFreqValues[i] intValue]` just check

Comment: so..NSInteger centreValues = [16]?

Comment: This answer is misleading. In Objective-C you can't create an array of integers (not directly) and you can't do this via typecasting.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. This way is easy.

```
NSArray *centreFreqValues = @[@250, @750, @1250, @1750, @2250, @2750, @3250, @3750, @4250, @5250, @5750, @6250, @6750, @7250, @7750];

for (id value in centreFreqValues) {

    NSLog(@" here is each integer %d", [value integerValue]);
}
```